Exterior powers of Weyl algebra
I'm working with first Weyl algebra $\frac{k[x,y]}{<xy-yx-1>}$and I want to compute its cohomology using Koszul complex, so I need to find its exterior powers as a module over ground field k, how can I do it? I would be really happy if you show for example second or third exterior power

What do you mean "find as a module over base field"? It is just a countably-infinite dimensional vector space. You can try to find a good basis for this vector space, but that's a different question.

Ok ,I'm new to this, I took definition from wikipedia,and tried to ise it in my case. Would be so kind to give some ideas of what should I do to find Koszul complex through exterior powers for Weyl algebra,maybe I should use Weyl algebra over k[x,y] instead?
